# Paypal API how to send funds and charge fees to recipient

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to develop a flow with PHP t send funds to our community.

When we sell a product, we receive amount from a customer, and after certain days send the amount to seller.

I have used PayPal payouts API for send money to seller, but, when I send funds, PayPal charge fees on my account... the seller receives a full amount.

How I can send the amount to seller without charging fees to my funds?

Answer (score 0):

> How to send funds and charge fees to recipient

What you are asking is a simple accounting matter. Calculate the fee that will be charged, and send your amount to the recipient *minus* that fee amount.